# What is the difference between indexOf() and search()?

Tags: javascript, string

Being fairly new to JavaScript, I'm unable to discern when to use each of these.

Can anyone help clarify this for me?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

If your situation requires the use of a regular expression, use the `search()` method, otherwise; the `indexOf()` method is more performant.

Comment: any reference to support this claim?

Comment: Also, `search` will evaluate a string into a regex even if you don't want to.

Comment: @cregox's comment is important - try `"hello.".search(".")` - it returns 0, not 5 because `.` is the regex token for "any character"

Comment: 'hello'.indexOf(undefined) returns -1, 'hello'.search(undefined) returns 0

Answer (score 44):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is for plain substrings, [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) is for regular expressions.

Answer (score 18):

**indexOf() and search()**

- **common in both**

  i) return the first occurrence of searched value

  ii) return -1 if no match found

  ```
  let str='Book is booked for delivery'
  str.indexOf('b')   // returns position 8
  str.search('b')    // returns position 8
  ```

---

- **special in indexOf()**

  i) you can give starting search position as a second argument

  ```
  str.indexOf('k')   // 3
  str.indexOf('k',4) // 11 (it start search from 4th position)
  ```

---

- **special in search()**

search value can be regular expression

```
str.search('book') // 8
str.search(/book/i)  // 0   ( /i =case-insensitive   (Book == book)
```

[reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp)

Answer (score 15):

The search function ([one description here](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-search.php)) takes a regular expression, which allows you to match against more sophisticated patters, case-insensitive strings, etc., while indexOf ([one description here](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-indexOf.php)) simply matches a literal string. However, indexOf also allows you to specify a beginning index.

Answer (score 7):

I think the main difference is that search accept regular expressions.

Check this reference:

- [search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp)
- [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Answer (score 4):

IndexOf() - it accepts string literals or string objects but **not** regular expressions. It also accepts a zero-based integer value to start its search from, e.g.:

1. "babyelephant".indexOf("e"); // gives you 4
2. "babyelephant".indexOf("e",5); // gives you 6 as the search
   starts from 6th position or 5th index.
3. var m= /e/;  "babyelephant".indexOf(m); //gives -1 as it doesnt
   accepts regular expressions.

Search() - accepts both string literals or string objects and regular expressions. But it doesn't accepts a index to start the search from.

Comment: What does it return for `"baby/e/lephant".indexOf(m);`?

Comment: good one.. it will return 4..because /e/ string is present..but if you want to find a regex "e" you aren't going to get the desired result. UMM maybe i should modify my answer to indexOf() tries to find the regex as a string literal and not as a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Search finds it's matches with a regular expression, but has no offsets.  IndexOf uses literals to match, but has an offset.

[IndexOf](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-indexOf.php)

[Search](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-search.php)

Comment: Search *does* return an offset. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the other considerations already mentioned indexOf is faster by a very large margin, if you don't need to do funky regex and are just doing a simple find then do not use search.
robisrob asked for some evidence so I whipped up a quick test.

```
Starting...
  IndexOf test - loop count 10000000
  IndexOf test end - duration: 4.600000023841858ms
  Search test - loop count 10000000
  Search test end - duration: 1221.6999999284744ms
All Done
```

That is a significant difference, only use search if you are going to be using regular expressions.

I can post the test code if anyone is interested.

Answer (score -1):

Without a [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp), there is no practical difference between [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) and [search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp).

The below example gives a live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/e6q1679k/):

```js
function FromSearch() {

  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerText;
  var n = str.search("difference");
  document.getElementById("Location").innerHTML = n;
}

function FromindexOf() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerText;
  var n = str.indexOf("difference");
  document.getElementById("Location").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Without a <a href='http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp'>regex</a>, there is no practical difference between <a href='http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp'>indexOf</a> and <a href='http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp'>search</a>
</p>

<button onclick="FromSearch()">From search</button>

<button onclick="FromindexOf()">From indexOf</button>

<p>Location of difference in the above sentence is:</p>

<mark id="Location"></mark>
```

Comment: There is a significant difference: `search` converts a string into a `RegExp`, so for instance, `str.search("d........e");` will also match at character 39.