# How do I check if string contains substring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring, contains

I have a shopping cart that displays product options in a dropdown menu and if they select "yes", I want to make some other fields on the page visible.

The problem is that the shopping cart also includes the price modifier in the text, which can be different for each product. The following code works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[id="Engraving"]').change(function() {
        var str = $('select[id="Engraving"] option:selected').text();
        if (str == "Yes (+ $6.95)") {
            $('.engraving').show();
        } else {
            $('.engraving').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

However I would rather use something like this, which doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[id="Engraving"]').change(function() {
        var str = $('select[id="Engraving"] option:selected').text();
        if (str *= "Yes") {
            $('.engraving').show();
        } else {
            $('.engraving').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I only want to perform the action if the selected option contains the word "Yes", and would ignore the price modifier.

Comment: Change your selector from `$('select[id="Engraving"]')` to `$('#Engraving')`. It will be faster. And inside the `change` handler, `this` refers to the `#Engraving` element, so you can do `$(this).find('option:selected')`.

Comment: How about :contains selector?

Comment: What this has to do with jQuery? This is pure JavaScript question.

Answer (score 2370, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (str.indexOf("Yes") >= 0)
```

...or you can use the tilde operator:

```
if (~str.indexOf("Yes"))
```

This works because `indexOf()` returns `-1` if the string wasn't found at all.

Note that this is case-sensitive.
If you want a case-insensitive search, you can write

```
if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf("yes") >= 0)
```

Or:

```
if (/yes/i.test(str))
```

The latter is a **regular expression** or **regex**.

Regex breakdown:

- `/` indicates this is a regex
- `yes` means that the regex will find those exact characters in that exact order
- `/` ends the regex
- `i` sets the regex as case-*in*sensitive
- `.test(str)` determines if the regular expression matches `str`
  To sum it up, it means it will see if it can find the letters `y`, `e`, and `s` in that exact order, case-insensitively, in the variable `str`

Comment: Can anyone explain the `if (/yes/i.test(str))`?

Comment: @DrewS: That's a regex literal.

Answer (score 137):

You could use [search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) or [match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) for this.

`str.search( 'Yes' )`

will return the position of the match, or -1 if it isn't found.

Comment: Good to know alternatives but using indexOf is faster. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354110/in-javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-indexof-and-search

Comment: Be aware `search` uses regular expressions, so `'abc'.search('.') > -1` returns true even if there is no `.` character.

Answer (score 61):

It's pretty late to write this answer, but I thought of including it anyhow. `String.prototype` now has a method `includes` which can check for substring. This method is case sensitive.

```
var str = 'It was a good date';
console.log(str.includes('good')); // shows true
console.log(str.includes('Good')); // shows false
```

To check for a substring, the following approach can be taken:

```
if (mainString.toLowerCase().includes(substringToCheck.toLowerCase())) {
    // mainString contains substringToCheck
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to know more.

Comment: how does this compare in performance?

Answer (score 29):

Another way:

```
var testStr = "This is a test";

if(testStr.contains("test")){
    alert("String Found");
}
```

** Tested on Firefox, Safari 6 and Chrome 36 **

Comment: getting error `testStr.contains` is not a function

Answer (score 21):

ECMAScript 6 introduces [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), previously named `contains`.

It can be used like this:

```
'foobar'.includes('foo'); // true
'foobar'.includes('baz'); // false
```

It also accepts an optional second argument which specifies the position at which to begin searching:

```
'foobar'.includes('foo', 1); // false
'foobar'.includes('bar', 1); // true
```

It can be [polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill) to make it work on old browsers.

Answer (score 13):

> The includes() method determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning true or false as appropriate.
>
> Syntax :-string.includes(searchString[, position])
>
> searchString:-A string to be searched for within this string.
>
> position:-Optional. The position in this string at which to begin searching for searchString; defaults to 0.

```
string = 'LOL';
console.log(string.includes('lol')); // returns false 
console.log(string.includes('LOL')); // returns true
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this Polyfill in ie and chrome

```
if (!('contains' in String.prototype)) {
    String.prototype.contains = function (str, startIndex) {
        "use strict";
        return -1 !== String.prototype.indexOf.call(this, str, startIndex);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are capable of using libraries, you may find that [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) JS library is quite useful. In this case, go ahead and check `_.contains()` (replaced by `_.includes()` as of v4).

(Note Lo-Dash convention is naming the library object _.
Don't forget to check installation in the same page to set it up for your project.)

```
_.contains("foo", "oo");     // → true
_.contains("foo", "bar");    // → false
// Equivalent with:
_("foo").contains("oo");     // → true
_("foo").contains("bar");    // → false
```

In your case, go ahead and use:

```
_.contains(str, "Yes");
// or:
_(str).contains("Yes");
```

..whichever one you like better.

Answer (score 4):

I know that best way is `str.indexOf(s) !== -1;` http://hayageek.com/javascript-string-contains/

I suggest another way(`str.replace(s1, "") !== str`):

```js
var str = "Hello World!", s1 = "ello", s2 = "elloo";
alert(str.replace(s1, "") !== str);
alert(str.replace(s2, "") !== str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if the exact word is contained in a string. E.g.:

```
function containsWord(haystack, needle) {
    return (" " + haystack + " ").indexOf(" " + needle + " ") !== -1;
}
```

Usage:

```
containsWord("red green blue", "red"); // true
containsWord("red green blue", "green"); // true
containsWord("red green blue", "blue"); // true
containsWord("red green blue", "yellow"); // false
```

This is how jQuery does its hasClass method.

Answer (score 0):

you can define an extension method and use it later.

```
String.prototype.contains = function(it) 
{ 
   return this.indexOf(it) != -1; 
};
```

so that you can use in your page anywhere like:

```
var str="hello how are you";
str.contains("are");
```

which returns **true**.

Refer below post for more extension helper methods.
[Javascript helper methods](http://spshell.blogspot.in/2015/03/jqery-helper-methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me as there were blank spaces  but this is what I did

```
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        bottab.style.display="none";
        bottab2.style.display="none";
        if (td) {
        var getvar=td.outerText.replace(/\s+/, "") ;

            if (getvar==filter){
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            }else{
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }

        }
    }
```