# Equivalent of ASP's .Contains method

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)
>   [Jquery: How to see if string contains substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480771/jquery-how-to-see-if-string-contains-substring)

In ASP .NET C# I use:

```
string aa = "aa bb";
if (aa.Contains("aa"))
   { 
       //Some task       
   }
```

I want to same thing in client side means in JQuery. Something like below:

```
var aa = "aa bb";
if(aa. -----want help here){
}
```

Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the [`String.indexOf()` <sup>MDN Docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method

```
if( aa.indexOf('aa') != -1 ){
// do whatever
}
```

---

**Update**

Since ES6, there is a [`String.includes()` <sup>MDN Docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) so you can do

```
if( aa.includes('aa') ){
// do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need jQuery for this. It can be achieved with simple pure JavaScript:

```
var aa = "aa bb";
if(aa.indexOf("aa") >= 0){
   //some task
}
```

The method `indexOf` will return the first index of the given substring in the string, or -1 if such substring does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

C#'s implementation of `.Contains` is actually a wrapper on it's implementation of `.IndexOf`.  Therefore you can create your own `.Contains` function in javascript like this:

```
String.prototype.Contains = function (s) {
    return this.indexOf(s) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you use indexOf for that.

```
 var aa = "aa bb";
 if(aa.indexOf('aa') != -1)
 {
 }
```

> **But remember that indexOf is case sensitive**.

you can create your own `contains` method using prototype that 
can, if you want, handle that.

```
String.prototype.contains = function(value, ignorecase) {
    if (ignorecase) {
        return (this.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toString().toLowerCase()) != -1);
    }
    else {
        return this.indexOf(value) != -1;
    }
};

alert("aa bb".contains("aa"))
```

Source: ['contains' method in javascript, extend the String prototype and add your own methods.](http://zainshaikh.posterous.com/contains-method-in-javascript-extend-the-stri)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for more complex scenarios, or indexOf for simple ones.

```
if (aa.match(/a(b|c)a/)) {
}
```

or

```
if (aa.indexOf('aa') >= 0) {
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Since Java 5, `contains()` also exists and can be used the same way.

Comment: don't mix up java and javascript.