# Search for strings in object

Tags: jquery

How can I check via JQuery, if a object contains a string? For example I got this as a object:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Needle: in haystack</p>
<p>Anything: more text</p>
```

So now I want to check if this object contains one or more of this elements at the begining:

- "Needle:"
- "Something:"
- "Anything:"

In this case two elements are found in that object. Now I need the output in a variable of "Needle, Anything"

I tried to use `:contains` and `filter()` but I failed with that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var foundin = $('*:contains("Needle:")');
    if (foundin) {
        // extract part
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: show the code you tried

Comment: Try this `sentence.indexOf(word) !== -1`. Where sentence is the string you want to search into and word is the word you are searching for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see if string contains substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480771/how-to-see-if-string-contains-substring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var values = ["Needle:", "Something:", "Anything:"],
    found = [];

$("*", obj).each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if ( $(this).text().indexOf(values[i]) == 0 ) {
            found.push(values[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
});

console.log(found);
```

This assumes `obj` is your object of parsed HTML and useable by jQuery.

Comment: How can I remove the double dot to push only the word in the new array?

Comment: `found.push(values[i].split(":")[0])`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the end result you are trying to achieve is, but you could use something like:

```
if (str.indexOf("Needle:") >= 0)
```

where str is your object.

Comment: You beat me for 15secs :(

Comment: similar to this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480771/how-to-see-if-string-contains-substring ?