# Detect character in div and remove it Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div:

```
<h1>$340</h1>
```

I need to detect if inside of this div there is a dollar symbol,
If so - remove it

---

I'll explain again:
I have got this code so far so I manage to detect if the symbol is in the div, but I can't figure how to remove it and update the DOM?

```
var sign = $('h1').text();

    if (sign.indexOf("$") >= 0) {
     //remove the sign
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see if string contains substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480771/how-to-see-if-string-contains-substring)

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy using a simple regex

```
var div = $('your selector here');
div.html(div.html().replace(/\$/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what I have meant, without the If condition:

```
$('h1').text( $('h1').text().replace("$", ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var price = $("h1").html().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '');
console.log(price);
```

Comment: I still see the $ sign on the console

Comment: That is because this only replaces the first occurence?

Comment: Why the downvote? also I suggest going with .text instead of .html but that is splitting hairs for this example.

Comment: This will only store the reference, not actually replace it in the DOM.

Comment: @rlemon, replacing text is not effective in this case because there could be nested html elements that would be removed with .text()

Comment: @MarshallOfSound assuming you need to handle nested elements and throwing .html at it also isn't effective in the long run. In this limited example (as OP provided) .text is the optimal solution.

Comment: @rlemon I am interesting in how .html() would not be effective in the long run?

And yes, in this *quote* limited *quote* example .text works.  I'm saving Stack the hassle of having to answer "why doesnt this work" when .text() stops working for him :P

Comment: @MarshallOfSound For starters, because `<a href="/some/path?foo=$520">` is a very possible HTML string.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Very interesting point, that was a case I did not think of.  Too get around that you would have to recurse to all elements inside the div and use .text().  Lets hope OP doens't want `$` in his links :P

Comment: @MarshallOfSound making assumptions about what happens in the future is the cause of all bugs in software.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I completely agree, but I ain't writing out a 10 line recurisive thing for this guy to use.  He can do that himself based on what we have said in the comments :D

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$("h1").each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var text = $el.text().replace("$", "");
  $el.text(text);
});
```

Comment: Why you guys are assuming that he has jQuery loaded on his/her page?

Comment: Maybe because title of question and tags?

Comment: Only replaces a single occurence

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    var val=$('#demo').html().replace('$','');
  $( "div" ).replaceWith( val );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id='demo'>$540</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Jquery can select based on contents. See https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/.

What you need to do is:

```
$( "div:contains('$')" ).remove();
```

Comment: I think OP meant the `$`-sign to be removed and not the whole div

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var input = $("#input").val();
    input = input.replace('$', '');
    $("#input").val(input);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="type here..." />
    <button id="button">Remove</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the JQuery approach, I used `replace` on click on button to remove `$` from `input`.

Comment: Again this only removes a single occurence of a `$` sign

Answer (score -4):

```
function HasDollar() {   
 if($("h1").html().indexOf("$") != -1) 
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

try this.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.