# jQuery form field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below on my form fields to validate it's not empty.
If empty, a CSS error class is added.

```
if(!$('.order-modal input[name="address"]').val()){
 $('.order-modal input[name="address"]').addClass('ww-error');
  form_errors += 1;
}else{
 $('.order-modal input[name="address"]').removeClass('ww-error');
}
```

I also want to check if the same form field contains "P.O. box" or "PO box" or p.o. box or po box and if it does change placeholder text and the error class.

The code below works in a way but not perfectly as I want it?

```
if(!$('.order-modal input[name="address"]').val()){
  $('.order-modal input[name="address"]').addClass('ww-error');
    form_errors += 1;
}else if($('.order-modal input[name="address"]').val() == 'P.O. box'){
  $('.order-modal input[name="address"]').val('');
  $('.order-modal input[name="address"]').attr('placeholder', 'P.O. box not accepted');
  $('.order-modal input[name="address"]').addClass('ww-error');
    form_errors += 1;
}else{
  $('.order-modal input[name="address"]').removeClass('ww-error');
}
```

Thanks!
/Robert

Comment: This appears to be jQuery, not PHP.

Comment: Also, it seems correct to me. Have you *tried* it? Do you get any error messages? What happens when you run the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480771/how-do-i-check-if-string-contains-substring possible duplicate

Comment: Use val method to get the value.

NB Placeholder text won't be visible when the control has a value.

Comment: What's the actual requirement about po box?

Comment: Yes AlbertVanHalen it works but the placeholder is not visible. The CSS class is applied. How to change the placeholder also?

Answer (score 0):

there is no inbuilt hasValue function, instead of

```
$('.x').hasValue('Y')
```

use

```
$('.x').val() == 'Y'
```

Comment: Not like this?
$('.x').val('Y')

Comment: this way you set the value you want to compare it and check if its the same

Answer (score 0):

Complete code:

```
var $fld = $('.order-modal input[name="address"]'), 
    val = $fld.val(), 
    fldError=false;
if ($.trim(val)==="") { // or add required attribute
  alert("Field is mandatory");
  fldError = true;
}
else {
  var po = val.indexOf('P.O. box') !=-1;
  if (po) {
    $fld.val('').attr('placeholder','POBox not allowed');
    fldError = true;
  }
}
$fld.toggleClass('ww-error',fldError);
if (fldError) form_errors += 1;
```

Comment: Typo. Remove the `(` from `$fld(.val`

Comment: I also changed the last line to use $fld

Comment: Yes it worked with no console error but the original check for a empty field is gone.
And it would be good to set back the original placeholder text if no error. Thanks!

Comment: Updated to include a test for blank