# jquery check if page URL contains specific path

Tags: javascript, jquery, path

currently im using jquery to get the URL path

```
 var href = document.location.pathname;
```

the path im looking for is something like /clients/invoice/details/DynamicID/DynamicID

i need to check if jquery if the href contains /clients/invoice/details/ in that order in the path to do something. Can someone please help me - i tried the following

```
       if(href.match('/\/clients/invoice/details/\/')) {

       }
```

but i think im doing something wrong.

Comment: you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480771/how-do-i-check-if-string-contains-substring if you dont want to use regex

Comment: if(href.match('/\/clients\/invoice\/details\//'))   you forgot escaping /

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var href = window.location.href;
if(href.indexOf(‘/clients/invoice/details/') > -1){
     //your code
}
```

You can do with a simple indexOf function instead of complex regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `includes()` method.

```
if(href.includes('/clients/invoice/details/')) {

}
```

ref: [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)