# JQuery if/else statement matching a wildcard CSS name

Tags: jquery, class, if-statement, wildcard, indexof

I am trying to write an `if else` statement in JQuery, which can change an element's class by matching `'IN'` or `'OUT'`.

For example: I have several `<DIV>` tags that each have `class='IN-something'` or `class='OUT-something'`.

The below would work if I knew the exact CSS class, but all I'll know is that it contains 'IN' or 'OUT'.

So something like this:

```
  if ($(jRow).hasClass('IN-*')){
    jRow.attr( "class", "OUT-foo" );
  }else{
    jRow.attr( "class", "IN-foo");
  }
```

Does anyone have any helpful ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if ($(jRow).attr('class').indexOf('IN-') !== 1)
  {jRow.attr( "class", "OUT-foo" );}
else  
  {jRow.attr( "class", "IN-foo");}
```

Comment: Since you only want a boolean response, `search` is the appropriate method here.  However, your approach will work fine in this case, so long as the matched string continues to evaluate to true.

Comment: Agreed... this answer is totally legitimate (as is mine), and we both got down votes.  I voted up, Sarfraz.  I suspect someone (Mr. Kendall?) is a little too competitive.

Comment: @dorkitude: It doesn't deserve down vote, if i did not used what *you would do* !

Comment: Re-read my comment.  I did not down vote you.  I up voted you.

Comment: I am the reason your answer score says '0' instead of '-1'.

Comment: Incidentally, this returns -1 or 0; (not 1 or 0, so !== 1 will always evaluate as True..)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`attribute-contains-prefix-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/) if that will be the entire class value *(or at least that is the first class)*.

```
if ($(jRow).is('[class |= IN]')) {
```

This also uses the [`is()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method to see if `jRow` is a match.

[***Click here to test a working example.** <sup>(jsFiddle)</sup>*](http://www.jsfiddle.net/EtRdu/)

---

**EDIT:**

If your point was that you won't know what `foo` is, and you need to retain it, I'd do something like this instead:

```
jRow.attr('class', function(i,cls) {
    return cls.indexOf('IN') > -1 ? cls.replace('IN','OUT') : cls.replace('OUT','IN');
});
```

You can pass a function as the second argument to the [`attr()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method. That function has 2 parameters. The first is the current index in the iteration. The second is the current value of the attribute.

The return value is the value that will be set.

Comment: V Clever - in my app I'm replacing 'foo' on purpose in this case, but that's a helpful bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery data to store "IN" or "OUT", or add an attribute of your own with a business-logic-appropriate name that says "IN" or "OUT". The real problem here is combining classnames.

You could also break out the `IN` and `OUT` and use multiple classes.

`<tr class = "IN foo"/>`

```
if( $obj.hasClass("in") ){ $obj.removeClass("in").addClass("out") }
```

Comment: Really? Down-votes for two legitimate answers, just to promote yours?  Come on.

Comment: I didn't down vote but the "You're doing it wrong" is never helpful

Comment: @dorkitude - how can you tell who downvoted? just wondering... I'll up vote everyone so they stop whining over their imaginary points!

Comment: unfortunately the assumption here is that I can separate the classes; I appreciate what you're saying, but due to various legacy reasons, I can't split them at the moment...

Comment: Yeah, the advice is valid, but the "doing it wrong" attitude is obnoxious.

Comment: @hunter agreed. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var class = $(jRow).attr('class');
if (class.search("IN\-.*")) {
    jRow.attr( "class", "OUT-foo" );
}
else {
    jRow.attr( "class", "IN-foo");
}
```

Comment: Really? Two down votes, just for answering the guy's actual question accurately?

Comment: ok, if you get downvotes, consider the following: 1. [the difference between search and indexOf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354110/in-javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-indexof-and-search)-> indexOf is more appropriate here because we don't need regex here. 2. search returns -1 on not found and -1 converted to boolean gives true, so your answer can never work. 3. in regular expressions hyphens don't need to be escaped because outside character classes they don't have a special meaning. With 3 flaws and better answers available you'd be better off deleting your answer.