# Converting a specific if/else if/else to switch

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm struggling a bit here, so I could use a bit of an outside opinion. I've had to quickly (and messily) write a function full of if/else statements to get something done, but now I have some more time to spend on it and I'd like to convert it to a switch. Been wracking my brains on this but I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
// This is just the function, this is fine as it is.
var between = "...";
var val = x.value.split("&&")
    val.forEach(function(y){
        application.output(y)
        if(y.search("{")!=-1.0) {
            y=y.substring(1,y.length)
        } else {
            if(y.search("}")!=-1.0){
            y=y.substring(0,y.length-1)
            }
        }

// Below is what Im trying to build a switch out of
if(y.search("!")!=-1.0) {

            if(y.search("%")!=-1.0) {
                y=" NOT LIKE '"+y.substring(1,y.length)+"'"
            } else if(y.search(">") !=-1.0) {
                y=" !> '"+y.substring(2,y.length)+"'"
            } else if(y.search("<") !=-1.0) {
                y=" !< '"+y.substring(2,y.length)+"'"
            } else if(y.search("...")!=-1.0) {
                // Use the index & final index of between to slice the two values apart
                y=" NOT BETWEEN '"+y.substring(1,y.indexOf(between))+"'"+" AND '"+y.substring(y.lastIndexOf(between)+3,y.length)+"'"
            } else {
                y=" != '"+y.substring(1,y.length)+"'"
            }
        // If user is inputting operators   
        } else if (y.search(">") !=-1.0) {
            y = " > '"+y.substring(1,y.length)+"'"
        } else if (y.search("<") !=-1.0) {
            y = " < '"+y.substring(1,y.length)+"'"
        } else if (y.search("...")!=-1.0) {
            y=" BETWEEN '"+y.substring(1,y.indexOf(between))+"'"+" AND '"+y.substring(y.lastIndexOf(between)+5,y.length)+"'"
        } else {
            if(y.search("%")!=-1.0) {
                y=" LIKE '"+y+"'"
            } else {
                y=" = '"+y+"'"
            }
        }
        y=" and "+x.name.toString()+" "+y
        sql+=y
```

The function takes operators passed in via user input and builds an SQL query out of it. Not even sure if it's possible to transform it into a switch, but there may well be a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code is ok.

If it was mine.. I would just replace a few things:

- replace `search != -1.0` by `indexOf > -1`. [See why search -> indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354110), ("!= 1.0 -> > -1" for readability)
- use `;` at the end of each statement.
- second parameter in the `substring` is [already string length by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), you can remove it.

But it's a matter of taste and maintain standard across your codes..

```
    application.output(y);
    if (y.indexOf("{") > -1) {
        y = y.substring(1);
    }
    if (y.indexOf("}") > -1) {
        y = y.substring(0, y.length - 1);
    }

    // Below is what Im trying to build a switch out of
    if (y.indexOf("!") > -1) {

        if (y.indexOf("%") > -1) {
            y = " NOT LIKE '" + y.substring(1) + "'";
        } else if (y.indexOf(">") > -1) {
            y = " !> '" + y.substring(2) + "'";
        } else if (y.indexOf("<") > -1) {
            y = " !< '" + y.substring(2) + "'";
        } else if (y.indexOf("...") > -1) {
            // Use the index & final index of between to slice the two values apart
            y = " NOT BETWEEN '" + y.substring(1, y.indexOf(between)) + "'" + " AND '" + y.substring(y.lastIndexOf(between) + 3) + "'";
        } else {
            y = " != '" + y.substring(1) + "'";
        }
        // If user is inputting operators   
    } else if (y.indexOf(">") > -1) {
        y = " > '" + y.substring(1) + "'";
    } else if (y.indexOf("<") > -1) {
        y = " < '" + y.substring(1) + "'";
    } else if (y.indexOf("...") > -1) {
        y = " BETWEEN '" + y.substring(1, y.indexOf(between)) + "'" + " AND '" + y.substring(y.lastIndexOf(between) + 5) + "'";
    } else if (y.indexOf("%") > -1) {
        y = " LIKE '" + y + "'";
    } else {
        y = " = '" + y + "'";
    }

    y = " AND " + x.name.toString() + " " + y;
    sql += y;
```

Comment: I'm happy with that, an outside opinion usually helps. I wonder if you could assist with one more, though. The string that the user enters to build the query conditions looks like {&&}, where && is the split. So for example: {!2...5&&!8} would build `id  NOT BETWEEN '2' AND '5' AND id  != '8'`. The != works fine if they use a single digit number, such as 8, but any double digits will try to turn != into another BETWEEN. Any ideas? E.g. {!2...5&&!12} builds `id  NOT BETWEEN '2' AND '5' AND id  NOT BETWEEN '!' AND '2'`

Comment: here is working... see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4XgTn/. Also, check first if (yours is removing "}", only if "{" does not exist)

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks, André. You've been a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using map and switch-case combo but imo better remove all the recurring code segments & keep only one of them also while concatenating a lot of strings better do that in separate lines, That will improve the readability

sample...

```
function checkChar(c) {
    return y.search(c) != -1.0;
}

var len = y.length;

if (checkChar("!")) {

    if (checkChar("%")) y = " NOT LIKE '" + y.substring(1, len);
    else if (checkChar(">")) y = " !> '" + y.substring(2, len);
    else if (checkChar("<")) y = " !< '" + y.substring(2, len);
    else if (checkChar("...")) {
        y = " NOT BETWEEN '";
        y += y.substring(1, y.indexOf(between));
        y += "' AND '";
        y += y.substring(y.lastIndexOf(between) + 3, len);
    } 
    else y = " != '" + y.substring(1, len);

    y += "'";

}
```

Comment: This also came in useful. I don't know why I didn't think of using a function earlier. Thank you :)