# how to take out header from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm able to get response in this fashion from `server`  `{"html":"response header <!doctype html>MY Intrest is this HTML Block<html></html>"}`

What I want to remove `response header`  which looks something like this  `HTTP\/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate` till it finds `<!doctype html>`

here is my sample data:

```
{"html":"HTTP\/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Fri, 30 Dec 2016 07:33:08 GMT\r\nExpires: -1\r\nCache-Control: private, max-age=0\r\nContent-Type: text\/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\nP3P: CP=\"This is not a P3P policy! See https:\/\/www.google.com\/support\/accounts\/answer\/151657?hl=en for more info.\"\r\nServer: gws\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nSet-Cookie: NID=93=ntWba1QpElyHkWL02fhHB6zujRcM8Sb6dfSww39vgUSaNOg6ya2e6PCZ2BA1zYhP2w9qeCy8X416oWKhHKfBAa17kEgNiRoSU0kMbRfuyVtahTUYDpCqS7knxRPhYSyei3MpXIakXU9BepA; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 07:33:08 GMT; path=\/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly\r\nAccept-Ranges: none\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n\r\n<!doctype html><!-- THIS WHAT I WANT --><\/html>"}
```

How can I remove this `response header`?

My expected output: `<!doctype html><html>content goges here</html>`

Comment: Do you want to extract the string "<!doctype html><html>content goges here</html>"

Comment: @codeMan, you got me right thats exactly i'm  looking for

Comment: this is a valid question why `down vote ?`  any reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `slice()` method

```js
var response = {"html":"HTTP\/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Fri, 30 Dec 2016 07:33:08 GMT\r\nExpires: -1\r\nCache-Control: private, max-age=0\r\nContent-Type: text\/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\nP3P: CP=\"This is not a P3P policy! See https:\/\/www.google.com\/support\/accounts\/answer\/151657?hl=en for more info.\"\r\nServer: gws\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nSet-Cookie: NID=93=ntWba1QpElyHkWL02fhHB6zujRcM8Sb6dfSww39vgUSaNOg6ya2e6PCZ2BA1zYhP2w9qeCy8X416oWKhHKfBAa17kEgNiRoSU0kMbRfuyVtahTUYDpCqS7knxRPhYSyei3MpXIakXU9BepA; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 07:33:08 GMT; path=\/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly\r\nAccept-Ranges: none\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n\r\n<!doctype html><!-- THIS WHAT I WANT --><\/html>"};
var sliced = response.html.slice(response.html.search('<!doctype html>'));
console.log(sliced);
```

Comment: Glad to help. Just basic javascript here

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by searching the `<html>` or `<!doctype html>` (if you want to include) from the server response.

`var response = {"html":"response header <!doctype html>MY Intrest is this HTML Block<html></html>"}`

```
function get_only_html(response){
    html_content = response.html;
    return html_content.slice(html_content.indexOf("<!doctype html>"));
}
```

Now call this function and it will return only html

```
var data = get_only_html(response);
```

You can use `search()` instead of `indexof` but will [execute slower as it expects regular expression.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354110/in-javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-indexof-and-search)

```js
var response = {"html":"response header <!doctype html>MY Intrest is this HTML Block<html></html>"}

    function get_only_html(response){
        html_content = response.html;
        return html_content.slice(html_content.indexOf("<!doctype html>"));
    }

  console.log(get_only_html(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to extract the part you need.
`"sdfdd".match(/.html>(.)<\/html>$/)[1]`

`'HTTP\/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Fri, 30 Dec 2016 07:33:08 GMT\r\nExpires: -1\r\nCache-Control: private, max-age=0\r\nContent-Type: text\/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\nP3P: CP=\"This is not a P3P policy! See https:\/\/www.google.com\/support\/accounts\/answer\/151657?hl=en for more info.\"\r\nServer: gws\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nSet-Cookie: NID=93=ntWba1QpElyHkWL02fhHB6zujRcM8Sb6dfSww39vgUSaNOg6ya2e6PCZ2BA1zYhP2w9qeCy8X416oWKhHKfBAa17kEgNiRoSU0kMbRfuyVtahTUYDpCqS7knxRPhYSyei3MpXIakXU9BepA; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 07:33:08 GMT; path=\/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly\r\nAccept-Ranges: none\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n\r\n<!doctype html><!-- THIS WHAT I WANT --><\/html>'.match(/.*html>(.*)<\/html>$/)[1]`